# How to Display Data from MySQL Database to Android by inserting it into Table?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I'm Creating an Android App that shows tables which the data's came from MySQL Database. I have my Codes Running without Errors.. BUT the data from DB is not displaying on the Table. By the way i'm using Eclipse as my compiler.

This is my Database :

[image]

This is My PHP codes with Json :

```
<?php 

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($con,"qstatslite")or die("error");


$q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM queue_stats ORDER BY queue_stats_id DESC LIMIT 20");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
$json_output[]=$row;

print(json_encode($json_output));



?>
```

And This is My Java Codes for DB :

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class GetDataFromDB {

    public String getDataFromDB() {
        try {

            HttpPost httppost;
            HttpClient httpclient;
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http:///192.168.1.87/Projects/Callchart/selectall.php"); 
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                    responseHandler);

            return response.trim();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

And This is my MainActivity :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String data = "";
    TableLayout tl;
    TableRow tr;
    TextView label;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

        final GetDataFromDB getdb = new GetDataFromDB();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                data = getdb.getDataFromDB();
                System.out.println(data);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<Users> queue_stats = parseJSON(data);
                        addData(queue_stats);                       
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
    }

    public ArrayList<Users> parseJSON(String result) {
        ArrayList<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Users user = new Users();
                user.setqueue_stats_id(json_data.getInt("queue_stats_id"));
                user.setdatetime(json_data.getInt("datetime"));
                user.setqname(json_data.getInt("qname"));
                user.setqagent(json_data.getInt("qagent"));
                user.setqevent(json_data.getInt("qevent"));
                user.setinfo1(json_data.getString("info1"));
                user.setinfo2(json_data.getString("info2"));
                user.setinfo3(json_data.getString("info3"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());  
        }
        return users;
    }


    void addHeader(){
        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        label = new TextView(this);
        label.setText("DateTime");
        label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(label,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView queue= new TextView(this);
        queue.setText("Queue");
        queue.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        queue.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        queue.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(queue,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView agent = new TextView(this);
        agent.setText("Agent");
        agent.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        agent.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        agent.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(agent,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll);

        TextView event = new TextView(this);
        event.setText("Event");
        event.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        event.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        event.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(event,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll);

        TextView info1 = new TextView(this);
        info1.setText("Info1");
        info1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        info1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        info1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(info1,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll);

        TextView info2 = new TextView(this);
        info2.setText("Info1");
        info2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        info2.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        info2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(info2,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll);

        TextView info3 = new TextView(this);
        info3.setText("Info1");
        info3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        info3.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        info3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(info3,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll);

         // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public void addData(ArrayList<Users> users) {

        addHeader();

        for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

            Users p = (Users) i.next();

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);

            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getdatetime());
            label.setId(p.getqueue_stats_id());
            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            TextView place = new TextView(this);
            place.setText(p.getqname());
            place.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            place.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            place.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(place,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

             // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me solve this one?

This is the output so far.. No data display:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have to encode the data you are getting from database into json with key value pairs. But you are directly sending the rows as result to Android Application.

Parse individual rows into arrays and encode the array into json.

```
$return_arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) 
{
    $row_array['queue_stats_id'] = $row['queue_stats_id'];
    $row_array['qname'] = $row['qname'];
    .
    .
    .
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Now you will get a json object consisting of arrays which you can parse in your java code in your Android Application.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late response.. i tried your codes but still i cant get the data's into the output table. The output is still empty

Comment: first, just try to get the json data on browser , check wheter you are getting data from the url in correct json format.

Comment: Yes i already did that and it run successfully.. i think the problem is in my Java code, the parsing is incorrect or there is something wrong on the codes..

Comment: try debugger. Debug your code using breakpoint on line like " data = getdb.getDataFromDB();" and parseJSON(String result)  method